# Rails rendering fields_for for a model that multiple has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, fields-for

I have a model `components` which belongs to a main container model. The `components` model has many `servers` and `services`. Basically all is fine, except it renders out two of each from because in my controller I set up the `fields_for` with this code:

```
@reference.components.build.servers.build
@reference.components.build.services.build
```

So it is clear why I am getting multiple forms, Is there a way to build the `has_many` relationships on one line? I have tried:

```
@reference.components.build.servers.build.services.build
```

and

```
1.times { @reference.components.build.servers.build }
1.times { @reference.components.build.services.build }
```

Thank you

**UPDATE ->**

Moving the code into a block seems to work (I was just guessing)

```
@reference.components.build do |f|
  f.servers.build
  f.services.build
end
```

That code is in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is to only call `components.build` once, or else you'll be adding one component per call to build

For example

```
component = @reference.components.build
component.servers.build
component.services.build
```

should work fine. The block form you've stumbled on achieves the same thing (I have a feeling that that was only added in 3.2, possibly one of the minor releases after 3.2)

Comment: Hey many thanks for the response. I am still using rails 3.1.3, but thank you for your solution. That makes sense, I knew it was something of that sort I just was not sure how to get it in one go. I like the variable solution. Thanks :)